# Getting ipaddress and location of every user visiting your website

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How do you get the ipaddress and location of every website vistor of your website through Asp.Net?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the user's IP use:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

You can use this webservice to get their geographic location.
http://iplocationtools.com/ip_location_api.php

Comment: just FYI, it's a property... not a method :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 string VisitorIPAddress = Request.UserHostAddress.ToString();
```

and based on the ipaddress you can narrow down the location: [find the geographical location of a host](http://www.private.org.il/IP2geo.html)

Answer (score 1):

Request.UserHostAddress won’t work if you're behind a proxy. Use this code:

```
public static String GetIPAddress()
{
    String ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    else
        ip = ip.Split(',')[0];

    return ip;
}
```

Note that HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR should be used BUT as it can return multiple IP addresses separated by a comma you need to use the Split function. See [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/james_crowley/archive/2007/06/19/gotcha-http-x-forwarded-for-returns-multiple-ip-addresses.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Well the following property should give you the IP Address of teh client (or the clients proxy server)

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

As for location, you'd need to use some GeoIP/GeoLocation plugin like MaxMind to figure that out.

http://www.maxmind.com/

Answer (score 0):

To get the IP do:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

And you can map IP to location using a webservice (slower) or a database (faster) like this:
http://ip-to-country.webhosting.info/node/view/5

Answer (score 0):

It's server technology-agnostic, but I'd recommend piggy-backing on Google's AJAX loader: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#ClientLocation

It's in Javascript and will even give you the person's city/state/country (well, it takes a guess based on IP address).  Post it back to the server and it's available to you in ASP.NET or whatever.